# Exclude controller name from routing in net core asp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using *asp net core mvc* and trying to develop a RESTful app. Let's say I have models like this:

```cs
internal class Album 
{       
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ExecutorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Executor Executor { get; set; }
}


internal class Executor 
{       
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

And I have 2 controllers, that I wrote like this:

```cs
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class ExecutorsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetExecutor")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        //some code
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetExecutors")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        //some code
    }
}

[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class AlbumController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetAlbum")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        //some code
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetAlbums")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

I can call `http://localhost:48234/api/v1/Album/1` and get `album` by `Id`,
I can call `http://localhost:48234/api/v1/Album` and get all `albums`. The same thing works with `executors`. So, what I want to do, is to be able to get `albums` by `executorId` and that my route would look like
`http://localhost:48234/api/v1/executors/1/albums`, which will return all `albums` for `executor` with `Id = 1`. The problem is that I would like to put this action into `AlbumsController`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("executors/{executorId}/albums")]
public IActionResult GetAlbumsByExecutorId(long executorId)
{
    return new ObjectResult(_service.GetAlbumsByExecutorId(executorId));
}
```

This code works just fine, but it puts `ControllerName` (Albums) at the beginning. How can I remove `ControllerName` from my route? Or maybe I shouldn't do this and just put this action to `ExecutorsController`? I decided to do it like this, because if action returns `albums`, it should be placed in `AlbumsController`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove [controller] from route path in controller and move it to the methods.

Something like this:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/")]
public class AlbumController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("album/{id}", Name = "GetAlbum")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
         //some code
    }

    [HttpGet("album", Name = "GetAlbums")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        //some code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("executors/{executorId}/albums")]
    public IActionResult GetAlbumsByExecutorId(long executorId)
    {
         return new ObjectResult(_service.GetAlbumsByExecutorId(executorId));
    }
}
```

Comment: It might work with [HttpGet("[controller]/{id}", Name = "GetAlbum")] but i havn't tested that

Comment: that's what I did right after your first answer. And it did work perfect.

Comment: It works as well on MVC.  After I removed "[controller]" from the ActionResult, "asp-controller" is ignored exactly the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get albums, you should place action method in `AlbumController`.

I'd like to recommend you this way:

```
[HttpGet(Name = 'GetAlbumsByExecutorId')]
[Route("{executorId}/albums")]
public IActionResult GetAlbumsByExecutorId(long executorId)
{
    return new ObjectResult(_service.GetAlbumsByExecutorId(executorId));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But the idea is that i want my API to look like www.site.com/api/v1/executors/1/albums